# Multiple Tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i just started leaning PHP and im having trouble creating multiple tables.
I created the first one but the second one isn't created.

```
    <?php
$nomeServidor="localhost";
$nomeUtilizador="root";
$password="";
$nomeBD="test";

$conexao=new PDO("mysql:host=$nomeServidor;dbname=$nomeBD", $nomeUtilizador, $password);

//põe o modo error para Exception

$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try{
    $sql="Create Database escola";
    //utilizar o comando exec() que nao retorna resultado
    $conexao->exec($sql);
    echo "Base de Dados criada com sucesso";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql."-"-$e->getMessage();
}
$conexao=null;

//ligação à nova Base de Dados
$nomeBD="escola";

$conexao=new PDO("mysql:host=$nomeServidor;dbname=$nomeBD", $nomeUtilizador, $password);

//Criar Tabela Alunos
$sql="CREATE TABLE Alunos(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Numero INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
    Nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Morada VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Telefone INTEGER(9) NOT NULL,
    IDADE INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL
    )";
$conexao->exec($sql);
    echo "Tabela Alunos Criada com Sucesso<br>";

//Criar Tabela Turma
$sql="CREATE TABLE Turma(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    ANO INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    Designação VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    N_Alunos INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    )";
$conexao->exec($sql);
    echo "Tabela Turma Criada com Sucesso";
$conexao=null;
?>
```

PS: Any help would be awesome. Im stuck with this for more then 3 hours and i already tried to search for something but i couldn't find anything.

Comment: can you gave us the output i mean if there are an error copy it if not say so

Comment: I think there isn't any error, because the message on the echo line was printed to the screen.

Comment: There is. Remove the last `comma` before closing the parenthesis.

Comment: @Jok6r  see my answer and tell me if there are something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last `comma`:

```
//Criar Tabela Turma
$sql="CREATE TABLE Turma(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    ANO INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    Designação VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    N_Alunos INTEGER(2) NOT NULL
    )";
$conexao->exec($sql);
```

Always test your queries in the database. If it's ok, then use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7
```

The right query is

```
CREATE TABLE Turma(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    ANO INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    Designação VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    N_Alunos INTEGER(2) NOT NULL
    )
```

Note last line of query ","

Answer (score 0):

You forget to set PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION for the second connect.

Let me suggest you to use just single connection.

```
$nomeServidor="localhost";
$nomeUtilizador="root";
$password="";
$nomeBD="escola";

$conexao=new PDO("mysql:host=$nomeServidor", $nomeUtilizador, $password);
$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql="Create Database $nomeBD";
$conexao->exec($sql);
echo "Base de Dados criada com sucesso";

$conexao->query("use $nomeBD");
```

and then proceed with creating tables. any error it will cause, will be revealed to you.

Answer (score 0):

the last query has two errors first the last comma

second the column `Designação` has non-English characters

you can either just use English name like that

```
CREATE TABLE Turma(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
ANO INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
test VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
N_Alunos INTEGER(2) NOT NULL
)
```

or add this line after create the pdo

```
$conexao->query("SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");
```

also you don't need to choose database in the first connection just the host and you don't need to recreate the pdo to use the database after you created it just use `use database_name`

here is the full code

```
<?php
$nomeServidor="localhost";
$nomeUtilizador="root";
$password="";
$nomeBD="escola";
$conexao=new PDO("mysql:host=$nomeServidor", $nomeUtilizador, $password);
$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conexao->query("SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");
try{
    //remove the next two lines if you don't wanna to drop the database it's just for test purpose
    $sql="DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $nomeBD";
    $conexao->exec($sql);
    $sql="Create Database $nomeBD";
    $conexao->exec($sql);
    echo "Base de Dados criada com sucesso<br/>";
    $sql="use $nomeBD";
    $conexao->exec($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql."-"-$e->getMessage();
}
$sql="CREATE TABLE Alunos(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Numero INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
    Nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Morada VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Telefone INTEGER(9) NOT NULL,
    IDADE INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL
    )";
$conexao->exec($sql);
echo "Tabela Alunos Criada com Sucesso<br>";
$sql="CREATE TABLE Turma(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    COD_TURMA INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    ANO INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
    Designação VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    N_Alunos INTEGER(2) NOT NULL
    )";
$conexao->exec($sql);
echo "Tabela Turma Criada com Sucesso";
$conexao=null;
?>
```

i removed all the comments and added code to drop the database if exist so i can test the code without needing to drop it manually every time i need to retest it